# Delete subsection in headline beamer default theme

Tags: beamer, templates

I'm trying to make a simple template based on beamer default theme. I have the following objectives for the headline:

- Use progression bullets just for sections
- Text: Section, Frame Title
- Optimize space (like removing any extra line skips)

I couldn't define a headline template with `\setbeamertemplate{headline}` that respects these conditions.
I'm using emacs+auctex+texlive2019.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{
  {"../template_gipsa/images/"}
  {"../template_gipsa/images/}
  {"./images/"}
  {"./images/}
}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}  \clearfield{note}}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

%%% template
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default} 
\usefonttheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\rm}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\rm}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\AtBeginSection[]{\section{}}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \hbox{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=0pt]{}
      \hspace*{0.em}\vspace{12pt}
      \insertframetitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
}

\defbeamertemplate{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \bigskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

\AtBeginSection{ 
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sommaire}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]{
  \begin{frame}{Sommaire}
    \small \tableofcontents[currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.43\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \vskip0pt
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  blaa
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have some questions, what is the interest of having frame bullets, only at section levels, it seems redundant with the highlight of the active section name. Also, what do you mean by *Text: Section, Frame Title* exactly ?

Comment: Any news on this ?